# DataView Sort does not work

Tags: c#, sorting, dataview

I am trying to sort a DataView in C#. But it does not Work for the Column "ArtNr.". I also tried to sort the columns "Menge", "Einzelpreis" and "Preis" and it worked. But i am not able to sort the first Column. In the Columns are only int values.

This is my Code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                DataRow row1;

                row1 = dtSource.NewRow();
                row1["ArtNr."] = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                row1["Bezeichung"] = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                row1["Menge"] = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                row1["Einzelpreis"] = row.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
                row1["Preis"] = (Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[1].Value) * Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[4].Value)).ToString();

                dtSource.Rows.Add(row1);
            }

            DataView dv = dtSource.DefaultView;
            //dv.Sort = "ArtNr. DESC"; -> does not work
            dv.Sort = dv.Table.Columns[0].ColumnName + " ASC"; //does not work

            DataTable sortedDT = dv.ToTable();

            return sortedDT;
```

Comment: `the Columns are only int values`.  No they're not: `row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();`  They look like strings.  That "period" after Nr looks like trouble.

Comment: Does your datarow have data in it?  In order for that to work "AtrNr."  should have been enclosed in square brackets [ ] on the sql side.(because a period in a column name is a one way ticket to a bad time)  Does the datagrid element still have the square brackets around the name?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
DataView dv = new DataView(dtSource, "", "SortColumn1,SortColumn2...", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a specific column to sort try this:
DataView dv = dtSource.FirstOrDefault();
Then If you will retrieve all data you can set dv to a List like this:
DataView dv = dtSource.ToList();